# Node.js Function Returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

The following Node.js code prints 'undefined', even though it found the file.

```
var fileFound = function() {
    fs.readFile('public/images/acphotos/Friedrich-EL36N35B.jpg', function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

console.log("Return value: " + fileFound());
```

How would I rewrite it? I don't fully understand the solution in the other thread I was shown.

Comment: `fs.readfile` is ***asynchronous*** !

Comment: Your `fileFound` function does not return anything.

Comment: Each function has it's own returned value. The `fileFound` function returns nothing that in JavaScript means _undefined_.

Comment: you can pass a callback function when function is called and return a callback with a value from a called function

Answer (score 1):

Because the `return` statements are inside the callback passed into `fs.readFile`.

the `fileFound` function never returns anything, therefore you get undefined.